# defining a function that contains an inequality

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I want to make a define a function `f(x,t)` such that `f(x,t) = 1 when 0.1 <= x <= 0.3`, and it is `0` otherwise.

I wasn't sure how to do this with the normal `def` command in python. I was trying to add `elif` statement in the definition but it's not working out for me.

Comment: `def f(x, t): return int(0.1 <= x <= 0.3)`

Comment: What is `t` for?
`f = lambda x: 0 if (0.1 <= x <= 0.3)  else 1`
`f(0.05)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `if` statement inside the function:

```
def f(x,t):
    if 0.1 <= x <= 0.3:
        return 1
    return 0
```

or, more elegantly, you could just convert the boolean expression to an `int`, since `True` will become `1` and `False` will become `0`:

```
def f(x,t):
    return int(0.1 <= x <= 0.3)
```

Also note that since the return value depends only on `x`, you can remove `t` from the function's definition.

Comment: thank you! Before I was trying to do it in a loop with the if statement, this makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(x, t):
    return 1 if 0.1 <= x <= 0.3 else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need `elif` here. You can define the condition as `0.1 <= x <= 0.3`, and since a `True` maps to `1` and `False` to `0` if you call `int(..)`, you can define this as:

```
def f(x, t):
    return int(0.1 <= x <= 0.3)
```

But I think it makes sense to return a `bool` anyway. A `bool` is after all a *subclass* of `int`, and both `1 == True` and `0 == False` hold.